# How do I do 3 animations in jQuery and loop them? (Timing is messed up.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, fadein, fadeout

I have a three different transitions for fading out and fading in my 3 images.

```
animate1 = function() {
    $('#changingImage').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#changingImage').attr("src","../files/others/image1.jpg");
        $('#changingImage').fadeIn('fast');
    });
};
```

I have this same function two more times, just replacing the 1s with 2s and 3s.
I call my three functions with this, repeating every 5 seconds:

```
animate1().delay(5000);
animate2().delay(10000);
animate3().delay(15000);
```

I'm new at jQuery, and I don't understand why the timing is wrong. All that happens is image2 (the original) gets replaced with image1, and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `setTimeout()` javascript function.

Documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){ animate1(); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){ animate2(); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){ animate3(); }, 5000);
```

This basically 'pauses' your JavaScript/jQuery code for 5 seconds before running the function and continuing.

Comment: This is even closer, but it doesn't repeat the entire thing infinitely. It tries to do them all at the same time strangely, so 5000, 10000, and 15000 makes it work, but it's still not looping.

Comment: @RobbyBennett You want this bit of code looped forever?

Comment: Yes, I want it to wait 5 seconds, animate1, same wait, animate2, again, animate3, and repeat the entire process forever.

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` does not repeat an event, it just delays its execution. You need `.setInterval()` if you want to repeat an event based on a given interval:

```
   window.setInterval(function(){
     setTimeout(animate1, 1000);
     setTimeout(animate2, 500);  
   }, 5000);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/bfb7jgaL/1/

Comment: It almost works perfectly, but it only repeats animate1() over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Yay! I figured it out with a bunch of help.

```
var animations = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        animate1();
        console.log("Animation 1")
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        animate2();
        console.log("Animation 2")
    }, 10000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        animate3();
        console.log("Animation 3")
    }, 15000);
};
setInterval(animations, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have a suggestion for you in case that you have more than this 3 image so you will create a new function for it ?
so what about to use only 1 function that will call it self with an attribute that define image name as it is the only thing is changing every time so you can use this better and less code ,you have just the n value will change every time will increase and the max value witch define how many image you want

```js
//if you want to set this animation for more than 3 image just change the max value
var max=3;
setTimeout(function(){ animate(2); }, 5000);
animate = function(n) {
$('#changingImage').fadeOut('fast', function() {
if(n<=max){
    $('#changingImage').attr("src","http://www.imacros-scripts-for-free.is-best.net/image"+n+".jpg");
    $('#changingImage').fadeIn('fast');
    if(n==max){n=1}else{n++;}
setTimeout(function(){ animate(n); }, 5000);
}
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="changingImage" src="http://www.imacros-scripts-for-free.is-best.net/image1.jpg" width="200px">
```